# Python csv file can't read all rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

There have total 36k rows in my csv file however it only processes 6k rows when I read the file. And it processes from bottom to up.

Here is my code

```
with open('ledgers.csv', 'r') as csv_ledger:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_ledger)
    data = [dict(d) for d in r]

    groups = []
    count = 0

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r['ref_num'])):
        groups.append({
            "ref_num": k,
            "items": [{k:v for k, v in d.items() if k not in ['ref_num']} for d in list(g)]
        })
        count += 1

print (json.dumps(groups,indent = 4))
print(count)
```

The count returned to me is 6199 only.

My file format as below

```
date       | ref_num | name        <---Header
2019-01-01 | H001    | shanny
```

Comment: If I’m reading it right, it looks like you are only finding 6000 unique reference numbers.  You may be fetching more than 6000 rows, but you are getting 6000 groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I’m reading it right, it looks like you are only finding 6000 unique reference numbers.  You may be fetching more than 6000 rows, but you are getting 6000 groups.

To get a proper count on the number of rows read from your csv file, try using

```
print(len(data))
```

Instead of

```
print(count)
```

Because `count` only indicates the number of unique reference number groups you have.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. How about the `print (json.dumps(groups,indent = 4))`, using this print I only able to see half of the result only

Comment: With the json.dumps bit, you’re printing the json created by the groupby. So you will hit the same issue, with the same number of groups being created as you have unique reference numbers.

Comment: I see, but the result also shows half only If I changed to `print (data)`.